# tryCatch() apparently ignoring a warning

Tags: r, warnings, try-catch

I'm writing a function that uses kmeans to determine bin widths to convert a continuous measurement (a predicted probability) into an integer (one of 3 bins). I've stumbled upon an edge case in which it's possible for my algorithm to (correctly) predict the same probability for a whole set, and I want to handle that situation. I'm using the `rattle` package's `binning()` function in the following way:

```
btsKmeansBin <- function(x, k = 3, default = c(0, 0.3, 0.5, 1)) {
  result <- binning(x, bins = k, method = "kmeans", ordered = T)
  bins <- attr(result, "breaks")
  attr(bins, "names") <- NULL
  bins <- bins[order(bins)]
  bins[1] <- 0
  bins[length(bins)] <- 1
  return(bins)
}
```

Run this function on `x <- c(.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5)`, and you'll get an error at the `order(bins)` step, because `bins` will be NULL and therefore not a vector.

Obviously, if `x` has only one distinct value, kmeans shouldn't work. In this case, I'd like to return the `default` bin divisions. When this happens, `binning` issues "Warning: the variable is not considered." So I'd like to use `tryCatch` to handle this warning, but surrounding the `result <- ...` line with the following code doesn't work the way I expect:

```
...
tryCatch({
  result <- binning(x, bins = k, method = "kmeans", ordered = T)
}, warning = function(w) {
  warn(sprintf("%s. Using default values", w))
  return(default)
}, error = function(e) {
  stop(e)
})
...
```

The warning gets printed as though I hadn't used `tryCatch`, and the code progresses past the `return` statement and throws the error from `order` again. I have tried a bunch of variations to no avail. What am I missing, here??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in `binning` I think you'll find that the "warning" you see is not generated via `warning()` but with `cat()`, which is why `tryCatch` isn't picking it up. The author of `binning` probably deserves a few lashings with a wet noodle for this oversight. ;) (Or it could be on purpose due to the particular way that rattle works, I'm not sure.)

It appears to return `NULL` when this happens, so you could simply handle it manually. Not ideal, but possibly the only way to go.

Comment: I was really hoping that wasn't the case, but I think you're right... I guess I'll just catch the error that `order` throws.

Comment: @AndrewSannier If this only (ever) happens when the vector you pass has only one unique value, I would probably simply check that immediately upon entry into `btsKmeanBin`, and have an `if` branch that handles that case.

Comment: I was thinking that, but I'm not sure that it'll be the only case. I can imagine some other situations that'd be problematic for the kmeans algorithm... by handling the error around `order`, I can probably get most of those... at least the ones that result in a `NULL` return.